# Музыка в проекте

Tags: c#, аудио, проект, visual-studio-2010

Доброго времени суток. Хотел узнать. Вот видел много кряков, а в них вшита музыка. Можно ли ее вшить в свой проект, чтобы сама воспроизводилась, без кнопок и прочего. Например, указав URL-ссылку на песню. Или нужно в сам проект ее вшивать? Подскажите пожалуйста как и что. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ - вшить звуковой файл в ресурсы проекта. Если воспроизводить звук нужно в 1 поток (параллельно никаких звуков от нажатия кнопок и т.п. не будет), подойдет [System.Media.SoundPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx) (он умеет воспроизводить только WAV-файлы, но с конвертацией у Вас проблем, я надеюсь, не будет).

Создаете событие FormLoad, в нем инициализируете ваш SoundPlayer:

```
private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Media.SoundPlayer Audio;
    Audio = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.ваш_звуковой_файл);
    Audio.Load(); Audio.PlayLooping();
}
```

Готово!

Comment: Я очень извиняюсь, но... Как создать событие "FormLoad". Я бы использовал гугл, но хочу, чтобы мне прожевали(можно без подробностей).

Comment: Вставил этот код - ошибок нет, но и музыку не воспроизвел. (Название вписал, формат .wav).
Замена "MyForm" на "Form1" выдает вот что: Ошибка 1 Тип "WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1" уже определяет член "Form1_Load" с такими же типами параметров C:\Users\Антон\Desktop\Form1.cs 105 26 client

Comment: Событие FormLoad проще всего создать, сделав двойной клик по форме в её дизайнере. Или же выбрать в свойствах формы (двойной клик в пустом поле создаст событие), скопировать туда код. Вот, для наглядности:
http://cs307502.vk.me/v307502907/cf84/sRSFathevaY.jpg

Comment: Есть. Звук воспроизводится, но... Он повторяется :(
Как его остановить? :((

Comment: Для этого есть метод SoundPlayer.Stop()
Почитайте о нем здесь: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.media.soundplayer.stop.aspx
Здесь о самом SoundPlayer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx

Comment: А можно было воспроизводить один раз, без повторения.
Для этого вместо PlayLooping() следует использовать Play().
Я так понял из вопроса, что звук должен быть постоянным, т.е. перезапускаться по окончанию проигрывания.
Опять же, читайте MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, если уж на то пошло, в ресурсы можно "вшить" поток байт, характеризующий сэмплы звукового файла. Но, легче, разумеется, вшить WAV файл, а уже затем воспроизводить его. Для данной задачи отлично подойдет замечательная библиотека **[NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/)**. Она позволяет достаточно просто манипулировать звуковым потоком(как входным, так и выходным). С ее помощью можно записывать аудио с микрофона, воспроизводить MP3, WAV файлы. Единственное, что плохо, она не стандартная, т.е ее придется скачивать. Но это того стоит: исходя их своего опыта работы с "либой", скажу, что она охрененна :)

Comment: Спасибо, искал подобную либу. Она умеет параллельно воспроизводить несколько звуковых потоков?

Comment: "Несколько звуковых потоков" - в смысле стерео звук? Или имеется ввиду параллельное воспроизведение двух независимых аудио потоков? Вообще можно распараллелить воспроизведение на столько каналов, сколько присутствует в устройствах вывода. Т.е тут все ограничено лишь количеством в системе аудио выводов.

Comment: Имеются в виду независимые дорожки. Грубо говоря, "a.mp3" и "b.mp3". Писал игрушку, вшил звуки для выстрелов/взрывов/бонусов etc. Глубоко копать не стал - использовал System.Media.SoundPlayer, а он, прежде чем начать воспроизводить новый звук, прерывает старый. Вот и спрашиваю.

Comment: Ответ: да. Также это может зависеть от звуковой карты - если она "доисторическая", то удивляться нечему.